# How to use jQuery in Meteor for building custom ui components

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to make custom dropdown menu, but which can work global, not only in specialized template. It's need to be useful like bootstrapp, with possibility to call everywhere using elements with special .class.

As for example, I want to use this in meteor in few templates but don't want to repeat my self:

**JS**

```
function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.initEvents();
}

DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;

    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2">Sign in with
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter icon-large"></i>Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github icon-large"></i>Github</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook icon-large"></i>Facebook</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly you use: React, Blaze or Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to build reusable components on jQuery because it doesn't support reactiveness. But Blaze can easily handle it.

The only way to build reusable components in Blaze is using templates. In your case reusable template may look like:

```
<template name="Dropdown">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2">{{label}}
        <ul class="dropdown">
            {{#each items}}
                <li><a href="#"><i class="{{icon}} icon-large"></i>{{name}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.Dropdown.events({
  'click .dropdown li': function (event, tmpl) {
    tmpl.data.onElementSelected(event);
  }
});
```

And then you can use it:

```
<template name="DropdownTest">
    {{> Dropdown dropdownConfig}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.DropdownTest.helpers({
  dropdownConfig: function () {
    return {
      label: 'Sign in with',
      items: [{
        icon: 'icon-twitter',
        name: 'Twitter'
        // ...
      }],
      onElementSelected: function (event) {
        //handle selected element
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This example is written only with Blaze. But you can use additional packages that allow simplify development of components like that: [blaze components](https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-blaze-components) or [flow components](https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-components).